# Can someone please help me edit my question better?

Tags: support

I just can't help it. I tried and seems I can't explain well maybe because my English sucks. I understand that maybe my [question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/540775/are-these-two-specific-use-of-a-phrase-and-a-word-giving-incorrect-false-informa) is not written well and it is not fitting well here, but I quite don't understand if you can't ask such problems here and on especially English Language Learners, what's the point of these sites.

So I think a compromise would be someone please help me edit it better. Because I'm really struggling. The problem is genuine. I know it's not easy to answer but if it weren't a problem at all, why would I ask it here.

Comment: Done. The edit should help clarify the question. But...it's still too broad and it is veering towards a proofreading request, which is absolutely off-topic on EL&U.